# Disable Javascript Parallax Effect on Mobile

Tags: javascript, responsive

Can anyone tell me how to disable my parallax effect on mobile? Thank you for your help in advance!

Here is my code:

```
$(document).scroll(function() { 
var y = $(document).scrollTop(), header = $(".page-nav"); if(y >= 528) 
{ header.css({position: "fixed", "top" : "0", "left" : "0"}); } else 
{header.css("position", "relative"); } });

function EasyPeasyParallax() {
scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
$('.landing-page-hero').css({
    'background-position' : '50% ' + (-scrollPos/4)+"px"
});

$('.hero-content').css({
    'margin-top': (scrollPos/4)+"px",
    'opacity': 1-(scrollPos/250)
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function() {
    EasyPeasyParallax();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend making use of **[window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)"); // Your desired breakpoint
  if (mq.matches) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      EasyPeasyParallax(); // Only parallax on devices at least 600px wide
    }
  });
});
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Grab the viewport width on load. Inside a scroll handler, check to make sure that the width is above mobile, and only call your EasyPeasyParallax() method if the width is greater than 768 (or whatever your breakpoint for mobile is).

```
var $vpwidth = $( window ).width();

$( window ).scroll(function() {
   if ($vpwidth >= 768){
     EasyPeasyParallax();
   }

});
```